# Draw an bitmap on a canvas with a custom shape

Tags: android, android-canvas

I want to draw an image with the following shape on a canvas:

[image]

The black must be replaced by my image. I currently draw the image as a whole. I just don't know how I can get that sort of shape in it?

```
    canvas.drawBitmap(header,0,0,mPaint);
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: I get the point of a shader. But how can I specify that shape? I need to do it with a rectangle. I can't specify a rectangle in a shape like that?

Comment: use a Path with lineTo methods

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to pskink I've got it:

```
int width = this.getMeasuredWidth();
int height = this.getMeasuredHeight();

BitmapShader shader;
shader = new BitmapShader(header, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);

mPaint.setShader(shader);

Path path = new Path();

path.moveTo(0,0);
path.lineTo(0,height/2);
path.lineTo(width,height/4);
path.lineTo(width,0);

canvas.drawPath(path,mPaint);
```

Just use a shader and a path to do the job.

Comment: great job!  i hope you learnt more than if you got a direct answer with a working code

Comment: Thanks a lot! Helped me as well :)